# Navigator in highcharts graph does not work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The rest of the chart functions correctly, and the navigator updates when I change the time scale, but resizing the navigator and scrolling left/right doesn't do anything (doesn't update the graph).

[image]

To initialise the graph I do this:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('highchartLineChart', {
    title: {
        text: 'MyTitle'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Time (days)'
        },
        type: 'datetime',
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: true,
        series: {
            id: 'navigator',
        }
    },
    series: []
});
```

Then I have an ajax method to populate it, which looks like this:

```
var highchartLineData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    var parsedDate = new Date(result[i].MyDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

    var lineItem = {
        x: parsedDate,
        y: parseFloat(result[i].Value)
    };

    highchartLineData.push(lineItem);
}

 $('#highchartLineChart').highcharts().addSeries({
     name: "My Chart",
     data: highchartLineData
 });
```

Then I tried adding this, just playing around with various attempts to fix it

```
var nav = $('#highchartLineChart').highcharts().get('navigator');
nav.setData(highchartLineData);
$('#highchartLineChart').highcharts().xAxis[0].setExtremes();
```

However it did not work. Although you can drag the navigator left and right, nothing updates. Sometimes it breaks it and the top graph disappears, but it comes back if you press 1m 3m etc.

There are no errors in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Highcharts needs the x value as milliseconds since 1970, it looks like you are generating a `Date()` object to use as the x value. See [API series<line>.data.x](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.data.x).

Comment: The regex is converting it into milliseconds (the date is coming from asp.net as `/DATE(192381924)/` and the regex just extracts the number part.

Comment: Yes, which you feed into `Date(192381924)` turning it into a `Date` object. Instead, just set `x: 192381924`. Also note that the number you used as an example is in seconds, not milliseconds. (unless it was meant to be 1974 that is).

Comment: You legend, that worked great! Could you post it as an answer for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you do the following operation:

```
var parsedDate = new Date(result[i].MyDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

var lineItem = {
    x: parsedDate,
    y: parseFloat(result[i].Value)
};
```

Setting `x` to be a `Date` object.

According to [Highcharts API on x values (for a line)](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.data.x) it should be in milliseconds.

> x: Number
>
> The x value of the point. For datetime axes, the X value is the timestamp in milliseconds since 1970.

So if instead you would do the following:

```
var lineItem = {
    x: result[i].MyDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1,
    y: parseFloat(result[i].Value)
};
```

it should work. (Assuming `result[i].MyDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1` gives you the time in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks mate, interesting how the date stuff on the rest of the chart worked OK with it as a Date (selecting 1M , 3M etc.)